# How to use Celery 4.4.6 crontab schedules within a Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery

I just upgraded from Celery 3.17 to 4.4.6. Unfortunately, I am experiencing some problems getting the crontab tasks to get picked up by the beat again. I think something has fundamentally changed but not sure what. The docs aren't easy to dissect...

I used to put all my recurring tasks in a method and then point in the projects `settings.py` to this schedule, like so:
`CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = CelerySchedule.celery_schedule`

The CelerySchedule looks something like:

from celery.schedules import crontab

"""
Check here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html
"""

```
class CelerySchedule():
    celery_schedule_match = {
        ############# ADMIN #############
        'upload-wee': {'task': 'exports.tasks.send_requests', 'schedule': crontab(hour=10, minute=30)},
        'get_wee' :{'task': 'imports.tasks.get_data', 'schedule': crontab(hour=8, minute=30)},
```

But that does not seem to get read anymore? Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade to Celery 4 I recommend following the [Upgrading from Celery 3.1](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#upgrading-from-celery-3-1) guide. Step 2 in the guide indicates that Celery 4 uses [new setting names](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#lowercase-setting-names). For example, `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` is renamed to `beat_schedule`.

With Django you'll want to keep using uppercase setting names. Run the following command to automatically upgrade your settings to the new names:

```
celery upgrade settings proj/settings.py --django
```

This also adds a `CELERY_` prefix to your settings so that they don't conflict with other Django settings. Reconfigure your `proj/celery.py` to specify this prefix:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Your periodic task setting should now be called `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` and your tasks should run.